# How do I create a biblography from mendeley in a specific style?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am using Mendeley to organize my citations. In the past I used the Mendeley word plugin but I am struggling with making a LaTex bibliography. I know how to export my bibliography to a .bib file and how to find the citation key, but the following questions remain:

- What commands are needed in my main tex document and any subfiles? I assume that `\cite{citationkey}` is for in text citations and that `\bibliography{library.bib}` is placed where I want the bibliography to be.
- I need to used a specific style for my bibliography known as [ACS ChemBio](http://www.zotero.org/styles/acs-chemical-biology). Mendeley supports it but how do I change my bibliography style in Latex?

**Example LaTex and Bib File**

The following example fails to compile properly in TexMaker and the citation is left as a question mark.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{style_format}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \centering
        {\huge Molecular Dynamic Simulation}
        % Bottom of the page
        {\large \today\par}
    \end{titlepage}
    \tableofcontents
    \clearpage

    \subfile{Introduction}
    \cite{Boulton2014}
    \subfile{Methods}
    \subfile{Analysis}
    \subfile{Discussion}
    \subfile{Conclusion}

    \clearpage
    \appendix
    \listoffigures
    \subfile{Appendix}
    \bibliography{library.bib}
    \end{document}
```

- ```
  @article{Boulton2014,
  author = {Boulton, Stephen and Akimoto, Madoka and VanSchouwen, Bryan and Moleschi, Kody and Selvaratnam, Rajeevan and Giri, Rajanish and Melacini, Giuseppe},
  doi = {10.1042/BST20130282},
  file = {:Users/NickolasGoncharenko 1/Google Drive/Mendeley Desktop Papers/Biochemical Society Transactions/Tapping the translation potential of cAMP signalling molecular basis for selectivity in cAMP agonism and antagonism as revealed by NMR_B.pdf:pdf},
  issn = {0300-5127},
  journal = {Biochem. Soc. Trans.},
  number = {2},
  pages = {302--307},
  title = {{Tapping the translation potential of cAMP signalling: moleculabasis for selectivity in cAMP agonism and antagonism as revealed by NMR}},
  url = {http://www.biochemsoctrans.org/bst/042/bst0420302.htm},
  volume = {42},
  year = {2014}
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Mendeley involvement is a distraction here. Bibliography styles are governed by the `\bibliographystyle` line, so here you want

```
\bibliographystyle{biochem}
```

You might wish to consider loading the `achemso` package as it offers control over the `achemso` and `biochem` bibliography (sub)styles.

Comment: Thanks! But after (a lot) of hard work I figured it out myself. For people having the same problem, you first need to go to the BibTex page of preferences window. Then select and enable BibTex syncing. You then need to copy the generated BibTex file to the working directory where you are compiling your latex document. From therein LaTex handles citations. For chemistry citations achemso is the package you need and you should read the documentation before using it. Any of the journals that are part of the American Chemical Society publications will have their style included here.